# Strings without twin letters

Tags: code-golf, string

Consider an arbitrary set of letters \$L\$. It may either be \$\{A, B, C\}\$, \$\{M, N, O, P\}\$, \$\{N, F, K, D\}\$, or even contain all the 26 letters. Given an instance of \$L\$ and a positive integer \$n\$, how many \$n\$-letter words can we build from \$L\$ such that no adjacent letters are the same (so for example A*BB*C is not allowed from \$\{A, B, C\}\$)?

This can be solved using combinatorics, but what those words are?

### Input

A non-empty [string](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2214/91472) \$L\$ and a positive integer \$n > 0\$.

You choose to accept only lowercase letters, only uppercase letters, or both, as input for \$L\$.

Also, note that a valid \$L\$ won't contain any duplicate letters, so `ABCA` is an invalid input and should not be handled.

### Output

A list of all strings of length \$n\$ that can be formed from \$L\$ such that no adjacent letters are the same.

You can repeat letters, so a valid solution for \$L=\{A, B, C\}\$ and \$n=3\$ is ABA, ABC, ACB, ACA, BAC, BCA, BAB, BCB, CAB, CBA, CAC and CBC.

Also note that \$|L| < n\$ is possible, so a valid solution for \$L=\{A, B\}\$ and \$n=3\$ is only ABA and BAB.

And yes, \$|L| > n\$ is also possible, so a valid solution for \$L=\{A, B, C, D\}\$ and \$n=3\$ is ABA, ABC, ABD, ACA, ACB, ACD, ADA, ADB, ADC, BAB, BAC, BAD, BCA, BCB, BCD, BDA, BDB, BDC, CAB, CAC, CAD, CBA, CBC, CBD, CDA, CDB, CDC, DAB, DAC, DAD, DBA, DBC, DBD, DCA, DCB and DCD.

The output doesn't have to be in a particular order.

#### Test samples

```
ABC, 3 -> ABA, ABC, ACA, ACB, BAB, BAC, BCA, BCB, CAB, CAC, CBA, CBC
AB, 3 -> ABA, BAB
ABCD, 3 -> ABA, ABC, ABD, ACA, ACB, ACD, ADA, ADB, ADC, BAB, BAC, BAD, BCA, BCB, BCD, BDA, BDB, BDC, CAB, CAC, CAD, CBA, CBC, CBD, CDA, CDB, CDC, DAB, DAC, DAD, DBA, DBC, DBD, DCA, DCB, DCD
OKAY, 2 -> OK, OA, OY, KO, KA, KY, AO, AK, AY, YO, YK, YA
CODEGLF, 3 -> COC, COD, COE, COG, COL, COF, CDC, CDO, CDE, CDG, CDL, CDF, CEC, CEO, CED, CEG, CEL, CEF, CGC, CGO, CGD, CGE, CGL, CGF, CLC, CLO, CLD, CLE, CLG, CLF, CFC, CFO, CFD, CFE, CFG, CFL, OCO, OCD, OCE, OCG, OCL, OCF, ODC, ODO, ODE, ODG, ODL, ODF, OEC, OEO, OED, OEG, OEL, OEF, OGC, OGO, OGD, OGE, OGL, OGF, OLC, OLO, OLD, OLE, OLG, OLF, OFC, OFO, OFD, OFE, OFG, OFL, DCO, DCD, DCE, DCG, DCL, DCF, DOC, DOD, DOE, DOG, DOL, DOF, DEC, DEO, DED, DEG, DEL, DEF, DGC, DGO, DGD, DGE, DGL, DGF, DLC, DLO, DLD, DLE, DLG, DLF, DFC, DFO, DFD, DFE, DFG, DFL, ECO, ECD, ECE, ECG, ECL, ECF, EOC, EOD, EOE, EOG, EOL, EOF, EDC, EDO, EDE, EDG, EDL, EDF, EGC, EGO, EGD, EGE, EGL, EGF, ELC, ELO, ELD, ELE, ELG, ELF, EFC, EFO, EFD, EFE, EFG, EFL, GCO, GCD, GCE, GCG, GCL, GCF, GOC, GOD, GOE, GOG, GOL, GOF, GDC, GDO, GDE, GDG, GDL, GDF, GEC, GEO, GED, GEG, GEL, GEF, GLC, GLO, GLD, GLE, GLG, GLF, GFC, GFO, GFD, GFE, GFG, GFL, LCO, LCD, LCE, LCG, LCL, LCF, LOC, LOD, LOE, LOG, LOL, LOF, LDC, LDO, LDE, LDG, LDL, LDF, LEC, LEO, LED, LEG, LEL, LEF, LGC, LGO, LGD, LGE, LGL, LGF, LFC, LFO, LFD, LFE, LFG, LFL, FCO, FCD, FCE, FCG, FCL, FCF, FOC, FOD, FOE, FOG, FOL, FOF, FDC, FDO, FDE, FDG, FDL, FDF, FEC, FEO, FED, FEG, FEL, FEF, FGC, FGO, FGD, FGE, FGL, FGF, FLC, FLO, FLD, FLE, FLG, FLF
NFKD, 4 -> NFNF, NFNK, NFND, NFKN, NFKF, NFKD, NFDN, NFDF, NFDK, NKNF, NKNK, NKND, NKFN, NKFK, NKFD, NKDN, NKDF, NKDK, NDNF, NDNK, NDND, NDFN, NDFK, NDFD, NDKN, NDKF, NDKD, FNFN, FNFK, FNFD, FNKN, FNKF, FNKD, FNDN, FNDF, FNDK, FKNF, FKNK, FKND, FKFN, FKFK, FKFD, FKDN, FKDF, FKDK, FDNF, FDNK, FDND, FDFN, FDFK, FDFD, FDKN, FDKF, FDKD, KNFN, KNFK, KNFD, KNKN, KNKF, KNKD, KNDN, KNDF, KNDK, KFNF, KFNK, KFND, KFKN, KFKF, KFKD, KFDN, KFDF, KFDK, KDNF, KDNK, KDND, KDFN, KDFK, KDFD, KDKN, KDKF, KDKD, DNFN, DNFK, DNFD, DNKN, DNKF, DNKD, DNDN, DNDF, DNDK, DFNF, DFNK, DFND, DFKN, DFKF, DFKD, DFDN, DFDF, DFDK, DKNF, DKNK, DKND, DKFN, DKFK, DKFD, DKDN, DKDF, DKDK
JOHN, 5 -> JOJOJ, JOJOH, JOJON, JOJHJ, JOJHO, JOJHN, JOJNJ, JOJNO, JOJNH, JOHJO, JOHJH, JOHJN, JOHOJ, JOHOH, JOHON, JOHNJ, JOHNO, JOHNH, JONJO, JONJH, JONJN, JONOJ, JONOH, JONON, JONHJ, JONHO, JONHN, JHJOJ, JHJOH, JHJON, JHJHJ, JHJHO, JHJHN, JHJNJ, JHJNO, JHJNH, JHOJO, JHOJH, JHOJN, JHOHJ, JHOHO, JHOHN, JHONJ, JHONO, JHONH, JHNJO, JHNJH, JHNJN, JHNOJ, JHNOH, JHNON, JHNHJ, JHNHO, JHNHN, JNJOJ, JNJOH, JNJON, JNJHJ, JNJHO, JNJHN, JNJNJ, JNJNO, JNJNH, JNOJO, JNOJH, JNOJN, JNOHJ, JNOHO, JNOHN, JNONJ, JNONO, JNONH, JNHJO, JNHJH, JNHJN, JNHOJ, JNHOH, JNHON, JNHNJ, JNHNO, JNHNH, OJOJO, OJOJH, OJOJN, OJOHJ, OJOHO, OJOHN, OJONJ, OJONO, OJONH, OJHJO, OJHJH, OJHJN, OJHOJ, OJHOH, OJHON, OJHNJ, OJHNO, OJHNH, OJNJO, OJNJH, OJNJN, OJNOJ, OJNOH, OJNON, OJNHJ, OJNHO, OJNHN, OHJOJ, OHJOH, OHJON, OHJHJ, OHJHO, OHJHN, OHJNJ, OHJNO, OHJNH, OHOJO, OHOJH, OHOJN, OHOHJ, OHOHO, OHOHN, OHONJ, OHONO, OHONH, OHNJO, OHNJH, OHNJN, OHNOJ, OHNOH, OHNON, OHNHJ, OHNHO, OHNHN, ONJOJ, ONJOH, ONJON, ONJHJ, ONJHO, ONJHN, ONJNJ, ONJNO, ONJNH, ONOJO, ONOJH, ONOJN, ONOHJ, ONOHO, ONOHN, ONONJ, ONONO, ONONH, ONHJO, ONHJH, ONHJN, ONHOJ, ONHOH, ONHON, ONHNJ, ONHNO, ONHNH, HJOJO, HJOJH, HJOJN, HJOHJ, HJOHO, HJOHN, HJONJ, HJONO, HJONH, HJHJO, HJHJH, HJHJN, HJHOJ, HJHOH, HJHON, HJHNJ, HJHNO, HJHNH, HJNJO, HJNJH, HJNJN, HJNOJ, HJNOH, HJNON, HJNHJ, HJNHO, HJNHN, HOJOJ, HOJOH, HOJON, HOJHJ, HOJHO, HOJHN, HOJNJ, HOJNO, HOJNH, HOHJO, HOHJH, HOHJN, HOHOJ, HOHOH, HOHON, HOHNJ, HOHNO, HOHNH, HONJO, HONJH, HONJN, HONOJ, HONOH, HONON, HONHJ, HONHO, HONHN, HNJOJ, HNJOH, HNJON, HNJHJ, HNJHO, HNJHN, HNJNJ, HNJNO, HNJNH, HNOJO, HNOJH, HNOJN, HNOHJ, HNOHO, HNOHN, HNONJ, HNONO, HNONH, HNHJO, HNHJH, HNHJN, HNHOJ, HNHOH, HNHON, HNHNJ, HNHNO, HNHNH, NJOJO, NJOJH, NJOJN, NJOHJ, NJOHO, NJOHN, NJONJ, NJONO, NJONH, NJHJO, NJHJH, NJHJN, NJHOJ, NJHOH, NJHON, NJHNJ, NJHNO, NJHNH, NJNJO, NJNJH, NJNJN, NJNOJ, NJNOH, NJNON, NJNHJ, NJNHO, NJNHN, NOJOJ, NOJOH, NOJON, NOJHJ, NOJHO, NOJHN, NOJNJ, NOJNO, NOJNH, NOHJO, NOHJH, NOHJN, NOHOJ, NOHOH, NOHON, NOHNJ, NOHNO, NOHNH, NONJO, NONJH, NONJN, NONOJ, NONOH, NONON, NONHJ, NONHO, NONHN, NHJOJ, NHJOH, NHJON, NHJHJ, NHJHO, NHJHN, NHJNJ, NHJNO, NHJNH, NHOJO, NHOJH, NHOJN, NHOHJ, NHOHO, NHOHN, NHONJ, NHONO, NHONH, NHNJO, NHNJH, NHNJN, NHNOJ, NHNOH, NHNON, NHNHJ, NHNHO, NHNHN
```

Comment: Is `A, 2` a valid input that should return an empty list?

Comment: Can the input be list?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, it's a valid input and it should return an empty list indeed. In fact, every n > 1 should return an empty list for L being a set with a single letter.

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Yes, it can be a list of characters or a list of strings of length 1.

Comment: @enzo, Can the input be a list of numbers? The language I'm using doesn't support characters or strings, only lists and numbers.

Comment: Yes, it's fine too! I will update the question to include the [standard definition of "string"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2214/91472) on Meta.

Comment: If output is strings, do the "words" need a separator between them?

Comment: @DomHastings I would say yes, so it's easier to distinguish them. A leading space is allowed though, if it helps.

Answer (score 12):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
fΛ≠π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P@3c7EedC843/P//39HJ@b8xAA)

Short and straightforward solution, the MVP here is `Λ`, thanks to its overload that can take a binary function and use it to check pairs of adjacent elements.

#### Explanation

```
fΛ≠π
   π    Cartesian power of L and n (generates all possible words)
f       Filter those
 Λ        for which all adjacent letters
  ≠           are different
```

Answer (score 8):

## Google Sheets, 88 bytes

```
=let(L,torow(A:A,1),reduce(,sequence(B1),lambda(a,_,sort(tocol(if(left(a)=L,,L&a),1)))))
```

Put letters \$L\$ in column `A:A`, the target length \$n\$ in cell `B1`, and the formula in cell `D1`.

[image: no adjacent letters.png]

The formula generates all possible strings of length \$n\$ from the alphabet \$L\$ with repeats, and while building a string, refuses it if its first character is the same as the one currently being prepended.

Ungolfed:

```
=let( 
  letters, torow(A1:A, 1), 
  n, B1, 
  blank, iferror(ø), 
  reduce(blank, sequence(n), lambda(acc, curr, 
    sort( 
      tocol(if(left(acc) = letters, blank, letters & acc), 1) 
    ) 
  )) 
)
```

`acc` is a vertical array, and `letters` is a horizontal array. The `sort()` function is array enabled, which means that the inner comparison and concatenation produce `acc` × `letters` results each round. `tocol()` then flattens the result, weeding out blanks generated by the `if()`.

Hat tip to [JvdV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100057/jvdv) for the `left(acc) = letters` pattern.

Comment: Porting my answer to GS gives me `=LET(L,TOCOL(A:A,1),SORT(TOCOL(MAP(REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(B1),LAMBDA(r,n,TOROW(r&L))),LAMBDA(s,IFS(AND(ISERR(FIND(L&L,s))),s))),3)))` for 126 bytes. A whole wopping 1 byte saved! =)

Comment: @JvdV thanks, that made me realize that the array expression and thus also the length test were superfluous. In Sheets, `1-regexmatch()` saves more bytes than `and(iserr(find()))` because it doesn't require `map()` in `filter()`.

Comment: Yes nice. I been looking at this for a bit and for 112 bytes you could use: `=SORT(QUERY(REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(B1),LAMBDA(x,n,TOCOL(x&TOROW(A:A,1)))),"where not Col1 matches'.*(?<c>.)\k<c>.*'"))`. Though this only saves 1 character when looking at your updated answer.

Comment: Here I got another option for 90 bytes: `=SORT(LET(L,TOROW(A:A,1),REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(B1),LAMBDA(x,n,TOCOL(IFS(RIGHT(x)<>L,x&L),3)))))`

Comment: @JvdV thanks! Using that pattern now. `if()` and `=` save one more byte.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```hs
l#1=pure<$>l
l#n=[c:a:r|a:r<-l#(n-1),c<-l,a/=c]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0fZ0LagtCjVRsUuhytHOc82Otkq0aqoBohtdHOUNfJ0DTV1koFMnUR92@TY/7mJmXm2BUWZeSUqSo5OzkrKJv8B)

Edit: Thanks to @xnor for taking off two bytes! I didn't know you could remove the parentheses in that context

Comment: The `(a:r)<-` works without parens

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->l,n{(?A*n..?Z*n).grep_v /[^#{l}]|(.)\1/}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZjBqlzHEYbXvss8weAoWBJXV8hOIBvZzJzq7mK6qVorjiMIloJAXAnpKhAc50WyESF-KOdpcv76JkQhGPWZU9V1-nPXp1ro7_989-GPf_n4j5dPf_pw9_LRb39--Ojr19e3P9z_5vjw9ubmm989vH1w86d3L94-__Ph8bd_-OUPr3_87q_3bx78_snjH6n41y9-9fnxtF0fvjo8-vpwPB2vD_V63PRrO10fTsda9thJsZNi27GWPbapYjttV4r89xt70R7Z7P-_e7JPP37UlqPp1fRq2_8ceLRPT63vnbT5pM0nbf6ERJv_g6NFr9q8afOmzabNdqxfe9a02bTZtNl0kOkg2-wq5_HZ9eFL0ee8PuSeyz0wc_-z_5777-P--7jntPHZ_vvZ_vvZ8WpLa2P1y__6loJJwWTTMrQsLf2CtVlqUdaUNWVN2aZsU7bpA03ZpmxTdig7lB3KDn1gKDuUXcouZZeyS9mlDwht68p2ZbuyXdmubN8_kFtqMS1Ny9BSib02xZxiTjGnmFPMKeYUc4o5xZxiTjGnmFPMKeYUc4o5xZxiTjGnmFPMKeYUc4o5xZxiTjGnmFPMKWYTs23Vx6ZlaKnEXmvqgqkLpi6YumDqgqkLJmYTs4nZxGxiNjGbmE3MJmYTs4nZxGxiNjGbmE3MJmYTs4nZxGxiNjGbmE3MTcxNzE3MTcxtq8Re28TcxNzE3MTcxNzE3NSFpi40daGpC01daOpCE3MTcxNzE3MTcxNzE3MTcxNzE3MTcxNzE3MTcxNzE3MTcxPzEPMQ8xDzEPPYKrHXDjEPMQ8xDzEPMQ8xDzEPMQ8xDzEPMQ8xD3VhqAtDXRjqwlAXhrowxDzEPMQ8xDzEXH_VhpiHmIeYh5iHmIeYl5iXmJeYl5jXVom9dol5iXmJeYl5iXmJeYl5iXmJeYl5iXmJeYl5iXmJeYl5iXmJeakLS11Y6sJSF5a6sNSFJeYl5iXmJeYl5iXmLuYu5i7mLua-VWKv7WLuYu5i7mLuYu5i7mLuYu5i7mLuYu5i7mLuYu5i7mLuYu5i7mLuYu5i7mLuYu5i7upCVxe6utDVha4u9NWvos899mtNveix797XWatpnVFrxWdFrCJWEdPOWVUz-K09s0etFekVqapZVbOqrKos-K09VlVWVfUXL6xOtzrddPoOGLXOWisyK6I9-1oRq0jdWuisXoS9CHsR9iLsRdiLsBdhL8JehL0IexH2IuxF2IuwF2Evwl6EvQhnEc4inEU4i3AW4Qz2WEWsIjpr1s3PuvlZNz_r5mfd_Kybn3Xzs25-1s3PIpxFOItwFuEswlmEswhnEc4itCK0IrQitCK0IrRgj1XEKqKzrAitCK0IrQitCK0IrQitCK0IrW7e6uatbt7q5q1u3urmrW7e6ub3dV6d0_fAb2TkOff_ruvhPKIeTtCTB8EgGASjCvycPC5vtdP5pvNN55tOuVPulAflcb681c6gPCgPygOkACkKyYF34B14B96B9_NlZxAMgnX6jpk8Lm-1MylPypPypDwpT8qBd-AdeAfegXfgHXgH3oEP4AP4AD6AD-DjfNkZBINgnR7AB_ABfAAfwAfwAXwAH8AHjQsaFzQuaFzQuKBxQeOCxkU1TtYkj8tb1EOn60HOCQbBIEi5U-7ny1vtrNP1IJgEKXfKL6cH5XG-vNXOoDwoD8oDpACpbj7RJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0SbRJtEm0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHGz5fTg_I4X95qZ1AelAflAVKAVDfvjEpnVDqj0hmVzqh0RqUzKp1R6YxKZ1Q6o9IZlc6odEalMyqdUemMSmdUOqPSGZXOqHRGpTMqnVHpjEpnVDqj0tHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRxtHG0cbRJtAm0CbQJtAm0CbQJtAm0CbQJtAm0CbQJtAm0CbQJtAm0CbOl9OD8jhf3mpnUB6UB-UBUoBUNx9oE2gTaBNoE2gTaBNoE2gTaBNoE2gTaBNoE2gTaBNoE2gTaBNoE2gTaBNoE2gTaBNoE2gTaBOMymBUBqMyGJXBqAxGZTAqg1EZjMpgVAajMhiVwagMRmUwKoNRGYzKYFQGozIYlcGoDEZlMCqDURmMymBU6hFXx8u_U3x-8_rV7Yv3h-_fXH32_MnTvz2-f_PwwfVBq9J6Pr767O3hzdOX3957cn249-XN3Zvnr74j9vTeVzfv375-dXf_i-vDFw9u3r95d7dnPty9v3px-z3_WvTxI89_Aw)

Input in uppercase. Start with a list of all \$n\$-letter strings, then remove those containing letters not in \$L\$ or double letters.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES10), 54 bytes

Expects `(a)(n)`, where `a` is an array of characters. Returns an array of strings.

```javascript
a=>g=(n,o,p)=>n--?a.flatMap(c=>p!=c?g(n,[o]+c,c):[]):o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcw/b8IwEAXwPZ/i8OQTjgcoC8hBEKBV@ZMZGQ8nQwIo8kWAulT97KkZQILx/e69O9MPXf3l1NzSwPtDW5qWTFYZGRSrBk0W0nRMuqzptqZGepM1HePHVbxbdl2vPA6twyG3I5sAWBCTaS4U9MGpR36L@ewFiuVkG6H3hLyYzT9Xi5fSZrG8rz6e8F18bSIMAFziEl3yZU7@KKUFUhDAIZgMfmPXc7hyfdA1V7KUVmtNDmVAfeZTkPGFQOiC2AWBo@QP238)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>             // outer function taking a[]
g = (            // inner recursive function taking:
  n,             //   n = expected length
  o,             //   o = output string, initially undefined
  p              //   p = previous character in the output,
) =>             //       initially undefined
n-- ?            // if we don't have enough characters:
  a.flatMap(c => //   for each character c in a[]:
    p != c ?     //     if the previous char. is not equal to c:
      g(         //       do a recursive call:
        n,       //         pass the updated value of n
        [o] + c, //         coerce o to a string and append c to o
        c        //         set p = c
      )          //       end of recursive call
    :            //     else:
      []         //       abort
  )              //   end of flatMap()
:                // else:
  o              //   return the output
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 5 bytes

```
↔'ÞǓ⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLihpQnw57Hk+KBvCIsIiIsIiJd)

generates all combinations of length n using the characters in the input string, then filters by those which are equal to the string with all adjacent duplicates removed.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>168</s> <s>160</s> <s>119</s> 114 bytes

*-8 Thanks to @corvus_192 for pointing out newline separation between values was allowed, and a massive -41 thanks to @tsh, a further -5 thanks to @ceilingcat*

```c
char*l,*c;f(n,i){n?(c[n-1]=l[i])&&(l[i]-c[n]&&f(n-1,0),f(n,i+1)):puts(c);}g(e,n)char*e;{c=calloc(n,2);l=e;f(n,0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NC4JAEIbP@SvEg@zYLmQflxYJsywq9BzhQQYzYduiDzqIf71t3at2mmGeZ94ZZCWiUnjJH56gHvIzkbSCWi4IniTzs0Ccqgxcl7SV6VnmutphPh0BNfLQB5jf368nQeBNSQoqweQVvMYAcyFuqL0xcBEUJn@kPVXJl33NK0nArq1BSZxwGTnUngC3BibNcdrWgH/zaNVP0n141GTcJVG6Wm8Ocf9aEu/bwGmX7NJtosms54nunUZ98Szy8qnY5wc)

Prints the newline separated output to STDOUT.

Comment: If you print the output newline-separated, you can replace `printf("%s ",c)` with `puts(c)`.

Comment: [119 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY5NC4JAEIbP@ivEg@zULmQflxYJsywq8hzhQQYzYduijA7iX29b96qdZpjnnWcGWYGoFF6z50DQAfILkbSEWi4IniXz00CcyxQ8j7SV6VnqeTrDfDoCasJDH2D@eFcvgsCbguRUgvHlvMbglglxRyJ1iosgN/7WEox0WJWycm5ZKQk4tW0VxA2XkUudCXDbMkrXbVsD/s2jVT9J9uFJk3GXRMlqvTnE/WvHeN8Kp12yS7ZHTWY9T3TvNOqLF5EVL8U@Pw)

Answer (score 5):

## K (ngn/k), <strike>22 21</strike> 18 bytes:

-1 byte due to @ovs.
-3 bytes thanks to @ngn.

```
{(|/'=':')_+!y#,x}
```

[Try it online](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJyr1qjRV7dVt1LXjNdWrFTWqaiNVnL2d3F193FTsjaOBQCCUwgq)

Comment: There is an barely documented feature of odometer here to save a byte: If `!` gets a list of string (or a general nested list?), it does `x@'!#'x`. Doing `!y#,x` will avoid indexing back into `x` at the end.

Comment: replacing `list@&mask` with "filter" can help shorten this - `func#list` or its negation `func_list` (note that `func` is applied to the entire `list`, not to its individual items)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>74</s> <s>67</s> 64 bytes

*-7 thanks to @Albert.Lang, -3 thanks to @Mukundan314*

```python
f=lambda l,n:[""][n:]or[c+w for w in f(l,n-1)for c in{*l}-{*w[:1]}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZlRb1zHDUafrV@xb5JSBWiT9iWIH1aXM0PsHZDPhqEHOZFTA6pkyA7QIshvd3fvx7MJkhYGPCMOh8vjORYB6eN/Pv/z@enbL1/ev368/9e7H@93jzdP3z1@dfX0/TfXzy9v3/3lfvf@@WV3v/vwtHt/dTz8@m/Xp8C7Y@CXrx5//fqX@7d/vfv17ssP958ePu1e796@vdzfLpc3u29vdqft/rityOV@0VfL7Wm53deynd3q7FZny76W7WxRleVY5e7u5uLVVvgPH3Gq9tvhYv@ng1v7cyP7RUFT0BS05X80ubc/96oPu7zV9Vtdv9X1P3Do@u9wtkVBXV90fdF103Xb11dbpum66brpuqklU0t2bIl/jFz3b46xb262/ek0t9Q8RS/X3P7eIusW2W@R/Za53bx8s0XebJE3@3PhJa2N2fmHXlI4KZxsWoaWqaX/Dm6x1KJMU6Yp05TZlNmU2VS6KbMpsylzKHMocyhzqPRQ5lDmVOZU5lTmVOZU6anMrsyuzK7MrsyuzL6VziW1mJamZWiplK1mij3FnmJPsafYU@wp9hR7ij3FnmJPsafYU@wp9hR7ij3FnmJPsafYU@wp9hR7ij3FnmJPsafYU@wmdlvKw6ZlaKmUrabJEJMhJkNMhpgMMRliYjexm9hN7CZ2E7uJ3cRuYjexm9hN7CZ2E7uJ3cRuYjexm9hN7CZ2E7uJ3cTexN7E3sTexN6WStlqNrE3sTexN7E3sTexNxnSZEiTIU2GNBnSZEgTexN7E3sTexN7E3sTexN7E3sTexN7E3sTexN7E3sTexN7E/sQ@xD7EPsQ@1gqZas5xD7EPsQ@xD7EPsQ@xD7EPsQ@xD7EPsQ@ZMiQIUOGDBkyZMiQIUPsQ@xD7EPsQ@z6LnY5xD7EPsQ@xD7EPsQ@xT7FPsU@xT6XStlqTrFPsU@xT7FPsU@xT7FPsU@xT7FPsU@xT7FPsU@xT7FPsU@xTxkyZciUIVOGTBkyZcgU@xT7FPsU@xT7FHsXexd7F3sXe18qZavZxd7F3sXexd7F3sXexd7F3sXexd7F3sXexd7F3sXexd7F3sXexd7F3sXexd7F3sXeZUiXIV2GdBnSZUg/GsLci76eMv5@s@1jK3Fc11pN6xq11vlacau4Vdx0b606a/C18tcetVa8V7zqrFVnrTpWdSz4WvlWdazq1He1sOrTqk9Tn0esqHWtteJrxZV/XCtuFa9nCvXTi6sXVy@uXly9uHpx9eLqxdWLqxdXL65eXL24enH14urF1YurF9daXGtxrcW1FtdaXGuQbxW3iquftd59rXdf693Xeve13n2td1/r3dd697XefS2utbjW4lqLay2utbjW4lqLay0uKy4rLisuKy4rLgvyreJWcfVjxWXFZcVlxWXFZcVlxWXFZcVl9e5W72717lbvbvXuVu9u9e5W726nd@c/3CH9dPiPm21//HPKOG2cTdTGOfJkw1FwFBxFXfdDsjlH6pbzWc5nOZ/lFHQKOgWDgnE4R@pWUDAoGBQMmg@aj2reQXaQHWQH2UH2w/lWcBQcVYdHrGRzjtStpGBSMCmYFEwKJgVBdpAdZAfZQXaQHWQH2UEOkAPkADlADpDjcL4VHAVH1WGAHCAHyAFygBwgB8gBcoAcaBNoE2gTaBNoE2gTaBNoE6XNyetkc45EbdThaUOOcxQcBUcUdAr64RypW9XhacNRckRBp@C5w6BgHM6RuhUUDAoGBYPmg@brlROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsROxE7ETsR2xHbEdsR2xHbEdsR2xHbEdsR2xHbEdsR2xHbEdsR2xHbH9cO4wKBiHc6RuBQWDgkHBoPmg@XplZ0g5Q8oZUs6QcoaUM6ScIeUMKWdIOUPKGVLOkHKGlDOknCHlDClnSDlDyhlSzpByhpQzpJwh5QwpZ0g5Q8oZUo7YjtiO2I7YjtiO2I7YjtiO2I7YjtiO2I7YjtiO2I7YjtiO2I7YjtiO2I7YjtiO2I7YjtiO2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdhxOHcYFIzDOVK3goJBwaBg0HzQfL1yIHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2IHYgdiB2MKSCIRUMqWBIBUMqGFLBkAqGVDCkgiEVDKlgSAVDKhhSwZAKhlQwpIIhFQypYEgFQyoYUsGQCoZUMKSCIRXbkDr/DL1@Znx3d3dxcfqJ/4fTrwBe7p9@erh6fHi62n7ef3393cWrx5vd083u4d8fH374/PDj7vVuO3r74e7i1fPPnz/@/PkYOv3qYPd0ffHq48uHp89Xn55fjqlXOr7evX69qwhVrq@//Bc)

Comment: `[...]if n else['']` can be `n and[...]or['']`

Comment: 65 bytes: `f=lambda l,n:n-1and[b+a for a in f(l,n-1)for b in{*l}-{a[0]}]or l`

Comment: @kg583  won't work for testcase A, 2

Comment: @Mukundan314 It looks like both of those fail the 'A', 2 test case, since they both return 'A' instead of an empty list/nothing.

Comment: `f=lambda l,n:[""][n:]or[c+w for w in f(l,n-1)for c in{*l}-{*w[:1]}]` seems to work.

Comment: 64 bytes: `f=lambda l,n:l*(n<2)or[b+a for a in f(l,n-1)for b in{*l}-{a[0]}]` (bug fixed)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
Z^t!dXAY)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyquRDElwjFS8/9/dUcnZxd1LmMA)

#### Explanation

```
Z^    % Implicit inputs. Cartesian product. Gives a character matrix where 
      % each row is a Cartesian tuple (*)
t!    % Duplicate, transpose
d     % Consecutive differences, computed along vertical dimension
XA    % Vertical-all: gives true for columns that only contain nonzeros
Y)    % Use as logical index into the rows of (*). Implicit display
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 70 bytes

```r
\(L,n,x=combn(rep(L,n+1),n))unique(x[,apply(x,2,\(a)all(diff(a)))],,2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZCxTsNADIbFmqc4pctZuEMDSF06lLQp0KpZyoAow7W9E5ESX7heIDwLS0Diodqn4aIwRTfZ_mz_tv6vb9P8qMlvZdVwfEq2fIWE9WSvix1xI8u2vhwBEkBF2Vslef2MoizzT15jhFsuQOQ5P2RKuRTgBTGCTu18ESrusvFG35Pl4fQ2DgGvIOhRL4xnHpwup08ORz0cp7P5YpV4FtbJstW57uGH9G7t8E3_qke7ZSMIBmyv6V0aywQdP6RhVrNCG8leq0LQ0EhxELtcMjdyzDQFnUP-551tGdmNfnS9f6uapot_)

Uses a rather loose definition of [string](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8964/55372) - a vector of character codes. Outputs a matrix with unique words in columns.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-nl`, 30 bytes

```perl
map!/(.)\1/&&say,glob"{$_}"x<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUBRX0NPM8ZQX02tOLFSJz0nP0mpWiW@VqnCxu7/fy8dfx0PHT8u03/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6@blAAA)

Comment: Nice! I did wonder about changing the input format for [my older version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/270184/revisions), but I didn't pick up on the `map` usage! Smart!

Comment: Looks like you can remove `!` if you change `&&` to `||` for 29 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUBfQ08zxlC/pqY4sVInPSc/SalaJb5WqcLG7v9/Lx1/HQ8dPy7Tf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7r5uUAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 42 bytes

Prompts for string followed by n:

```
n←m←⎕⋄⍎∊(⎕-1)⍴⊂'n←n∘.,m⋄'⋄(0=+/¨2=/¨,n)/,n
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tfx6QmQvEQOFH3S2PevsedXRpADm6hpqPerc86mpSB6nIe9QxQ08nF6hCHYg1DGy19Q@tMLIFEjp5mvo6ef@BZnH9T@NSd3RyVucy5gKz4AxnFyjT39sxUp3LCMR09ndxdfdxg0r4uXkD1ZiAmF7@Hn7qXKYA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, <s>23</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
▽≡(/×≡/≠◫2).⊏☇1⇡▽:⧻,
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAg4pa94omhKC_Dl-KJoS_iiaDil6syKS7iio_imIcx4oeh4pa9OuKnuywKCnt7MyAiQUJDIn0KIHszICJBQiJ9CiB7MyAiQUJDRCJ9CiB7MiAiT0tBWSJ9CiB7MyAiQ09ERUdMRiJ9CiB7NCAiTkZLRCJ9CiB7NSAiSk9ITiJ9fQriiLXil4coJnAiIuKJoSZw4peHZsKw4oqfKQo=)

```
▽≡(/×≡/≠◫2).⊏☇1⇡▽:⧻,
                  ⧻,  # length of the set, call it L
               ⇡▽:    # permutations w/ repetition of [0..n) with length L
             ☇1       # change to rank 2
            ⊏         # index into set
           .          # duplicate
 ≡(       )           # map each row
        ◫2            # windows of length 2
     ≡/≠              # reduce each row by inequality
   /×                 # product
▽                     # keep
```

Comment: huh, `/(☇1⊞⊂)↯` does the exact same thing as `⊏☇1⇡▽:⧻,` completely differently

Answer (score 3):

## Excel ms365, <sup><s>85</s></sup> 84 bytes

- -1 thanks to [doubleunary](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/119296/doubleunary)'s tip to apply `LEFT()` instead of `RIGHT()`.

Assuming:

- \$L\$ - Given input in the first row `1:1` starting from `A1` onwards;
- \$n\$ - Given integer in `A2`.

Formula, thus output, in `A4` spilled down:

```
=LET(L,TOROW(1:1,1),REDUCE("",TAKE(L,,A2),LAMBDA(x,n,TOCOL(IFS(LEFT(x)<>L,L&x),3))))
```

[image]

Comment: Save one more byte: `ifs(L<>left(x),L&x)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṗnƝẠ$Ƈ
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the alphabet on the left and the word length on the right and yields a list of valid words.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//4bmXbsad4bqgJMaH/8OnS///Sk9ITv81)**

#### How?

```
ṗnƝẠ$Ƈ - Link: Alphabet, WordLength
ṗ      - {Alphabet} Cartesian power {WordLength} -> all words
     Ƈ - keep those for which:
    $  -   last two links as a monad - f(Word):
  Ɲ    -     for neighbouring pairs:
 n     -       not equal?
   Ạ   -     all?
```

...if one didn't need to handle an alphabet of length one, then five bytes would do - `ṗnƝÐṀ` (keep those words which are maximal under neighbourwise not-equal).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
⊞υωＦＮ≔ΣＥηＥΦυ⌕μκ⁺κμυυ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjczA0qLMzRKdRTKNa250vKLFDQ88wpKS_xKc5NSizQ0NRUci4sz0_M0gktzNXwTCzQydBRAlFtmTglQHqjPLTMvRSNXRyFbU1NHISCntFgjW0chV1MTxC0FmhlQlJlXogFkLSlOSi6GWrs8Wkm3LEcpdpkJl5-btwtEEAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υω
```

Start with the empty string.

```
ＦＮ
```

Loop `n` times.

```
≔ΣＥηＥΦυ⌕μκ⁺κμυ
```

For each letter of `L`, prefix it to each string so far that does not begin with that letter, then concatenate all of the results together. (Prefixing each letter of `L` that the string does not begin with fails when there are no strings in the list.)

```
υ
```

Output the final list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

*-3 bytes inspired by a suggestion from [Fatalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41723/fatalize)*

```
gʰj₎∋ᵐ.ẹ~ḅ
```

Generator solution. Takes input as a list containing a string and an integer. Returns solutions as lists of single-character strings. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KGsOKCgeG6ieKKpf9nyrBq4oKO4oiL4bWQLuG6uX7huIX//1siYWJjIiwgNF0)

#### Explanation

This feels like it should be shorter. Part of the problem is that Brachylog starts getting verbose when you have to deal with anything past one input and one output.

```
gʰj₎∋ᵐ.ẹ~ḅ
             Input: list containing string and number
gʰ           Wrap the first element in a singleton list
  j₎         Concatenate that list with itself (second element) times
    ∋ᵐ       Select one character from each of those strings
      .      This will be the output
       ẹ     Convert each character to a list of its characters (i.e.
              wrap it in a singleton list)
        ~ḅ   Assert that this is the same as the result of partitioning
              some list into runs of identical elements
             ... and that that list is the output
```

To help clarify the ending bit: The predicate `ẹ` converts each string in its input into a list of its characters. The predicate `ḅ` finds all runs of consecutive identical values in its input. The `.ẹ~ḅ` structure applies `ẹ` to the list, then *unapplies* `ḅ` to that result, then requires *that* result to be the same list we started with. This is the same as saying that `ẹ` and `ḅ` must give the same result when applied to the list. So:

- Given the list `["a","b","b"]`, `ẹ` outputs `[["a"],["b"],["b"]]` and `ḅ` outputs `[["a"],["b","b"]]`. Those don't match, so the predicate fails.
- Given the list `["a","b","a"]`, `ẹ` outputs `[["a"],["b"],["a"]]` and `ḅ` outputs `[["a"],["b"],["a"]]`. Those do match, so the predicate succeeds.

Comment: `ḅl₁ᵐ` is 1 less byte than `s₂ᶠ≠ᵐ` to check that no two consecutive elements are equal.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to save a couple more bytes with a variation on that idea.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 41 bytes

```
"$&"+%Lw$`,.*(.)
$`$1$&$'
\d|,.+

A`(.)\1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9JRU1JW9WnXCVBR09LQ0@TSyVBxVBFTUWdKyalRkdPm4vLMQEoHGP4X4Xr0Lb/xjqOTs5cIBJMOLtwGen4eztGAnnO/i6u7j5uXCY6fm7eLlymOl7@Hn4A) Link includes test cases. Takes comma-separated input. Explanation:

```
"$&"+`
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
%Lw$`,.*(.)
$`$1$&$'
```

Replicate each line for each letter of `L` but inserting a copy of the letter before the comma.

```
\d|,.+
```

Remove the copies of `n` and `L`.

```
A`(.)\1
```

Remove all lines with duplicate adjacent letters.

Comment: Nice one! You can have a test suite if you use the current string rather than the original input from the history (`$0` instead of `$+`) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9JxUBJW9WnXCVBR09LQ0@TSyVBxVBFTUWdKyalRkdPm4vLMQEoHGP4/9A2Lp3/xjqOTs5cIBJMOLtwGen4eztGAnnO/i6u7j5uXCY6fm7eLlymOl7@Hn4A "Retina – Try It Online")

Comment: @Leo Ah yes, normally I have to delete the input number before the loop, but I was able to get away without that here.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ãʒüÊP
```

Inputs in the order \$n,L\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8OJTkw7vOdwV8P@/MZejkzMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X94bVmlvZLCo7ZJCkr2lUEJ/w8vPjXp8J7DXQH/a3X@R0cb6yg5OjkrxepAWHCGswuIaaSj5O/tGAkVdfZ3cXX393EDcU10lPzcvMGKTHWUvPw9/KDqHZViYwE).

Or alternatively:

```
ãʒDÔQ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8OJTk1wOTwn8/9@Yy9HJGQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X94bVmlvZLCo7ZJCkr2lUEJ/w8vPjXJ5fCUwP@1Ov@jo411lBydnJVidSAsOMPZBcQ00lHy93aMhIo6@7u4uvv7uIG4JjpKfm7eYEWmOkpe/h5@UPWOSrGxAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ã      # Cartesian product on both (implicit) inputs to get all n-sized strings using
       # characters from L
 ʒ     # Filter it by:
  ü    #  Map over each overlapping pair:
   Ê   #   Check that they're NOT equal
    P  #  Check that all of them are truthy
       # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly)

  D    #  Duplicate the current string
   Ô   #  Connected uniquify it, collapsing all equal adjacent characters
    Q  #  Check if the connected uniquified string is still the same
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-lF -M5.10.0`, 40 bytes

```perl
!/[^@F]|(.)\1/&&say for A x($;=<>)..Z x$
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiIS9bXkBGXXwoLilcXDEvJiZzYXkgZm9yIEEgeCgkOz08PikuLlogeCQiLCJhcmdzIjoiLWxGXG4tTTUuMTAuMCIsImlucHV0IjoiQUJDXG4zIn0=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
ŧĉᵐz
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FiuOLj_S-XDrhKolxUnJxVDBBTftjBWUHJ2clbjANJRydlHiMlJQ8vd2jASLOPu7uLr7uClxmSgo-bl5A2VNFZS8_D38lCDGAAA)

```
ŧĉᵐz    Take input L and n
ŧ       Find an n-tuple of elements of L
 ĉ      Split into runs of equal elements
  ᵐ     For each run:
   z        Check that it contains exactly one element, and take that element
```

Answer (score 2):

## **[R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>65</s> 64 bytes**

```
\(L,n,A=expand.grid(rep(list(L),n)))A[!rowSums(A[,-n]==A[,-1]),]
```

Assuming `L` is a vector of characters.

**-1 byte thanks to @pajonk!**

[Try it online here!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3HWI0fHTydBxtUysKEvNS9NKLMlM0ilILNHIyi0s0fDR18jQ1NR2jFYvyy4NLc4s1HKN1dPNibW1BtGGspk4s1ByzNI3UHI3ikqLigpzMEg0lRydnJR0lJU1NHWNNLgw5uBRE94IFEBoA)

Comment: This needs column selector in `[` to work (for me): https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3HWI0fHTydBxtUysKEvNS9NKLMlM0ilILNHIyi0s0fDR18jQ1NR2jFYvyy4NLc4s1HKN1dPNibW1BtGGspk4s1ByzNI3UHI3ikqLigpzMEg0lRydnJR0lJU1NHWNNLgw5uBRE94IFEBoA BTW, I also changed `==0` to `!`, so overall -1 byte :) Also, a link in the post to an online repl (like the one linked above) would be nice.

Comment: @pajonk Thanks! Love the trick with the ``!`` The column selector for some reason works on one machine, but I can't replicate it in general, will edit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 128 bytes

A Port of [@Arnold Palmer's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/270165/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZvfbpxJEUfv8xQfvrKFvQIWEHLWSOOp7i7cTZWiiAsrysXEmQQjM8k6DhBZkXgPbpYLuOFFeAV4GmbsxH9-J7ubldBKsafS_XV9XSd1thL5b_98c7I4W3z5rydbe6tXf16cr7ae_veX_3717A_Lk4vpt4vT1XT5YJqeL19Mf1x_2F6cv3yzP83Ozxfvnjy-OD9dvXy6sz_9bnV6MR1crZymPy3OppPFm-WbdeTx8uvtq-A0ffw6TVuzw_nW7s3HL2-_vbP8w8LZnYXYuQnMdcX88H7gcIaAPONQn3Goz5jrM-b6jLlmOl9nevN558N3Ox-XbG9tnrh-9atXvn7P61R3btfcuzD7v93Yof3QK5zNdYvpFtMtppf8_WWY2Q-ty6EmdqiJHWpih5rYZ9RWE_tksSWgWzSxuSY218RMEzNNzDQx08RMEzNNzPSSTS_Z1pf8HSTfUpp9dnxn68--ndLs949IySGP73_uKZ9lfZf1M1k_k_Nmsv5Y1h_L-uPZ593APK20UT_vj-o8FZpUaLJooGlgaKB-D1ZzSw3oKaanmJ5iekrRU4qeUvTlip5S9JSipzQ9pekpTU9p-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-XN5-_6C5Co_e7Df377rf7tR9SQzNeRjohppAcieE7HLsMuZWAd0dM7MuzIsCPDXvWsXrFL_5hHR4YdGXZkaMjQkKEhQ0OGhgzxP-1huHnDzZve_LrIgUhHBLv0rHVEOQ-epXe4jmCX3mFFlSuqXFHliipXVLmiyhVVrqhyRZUrqlxR5YoqV1S5osoVVa6ockWVK6rcUeWOKndUuaPKHVXuqHJHlTuq3FHljm7T0W06uk1Ht-noNh3dpqPbdHSbjm7TUeWOKndUuaPKHVXuqHJHlTuq3FFlQ5UNVTZU2VBlQ5UNVTZU2VBlQ5UNVTZU2VBlQ5UNVTZU2VBlQ5UNVTZ0G0O3MXQbQ7cxdBtDtzF0G0O3sU23-SyzH6Xffdovvt3sR7n-7_4xm5AzFAg5N3oyxI3BjcGNgST8CKv86BOrcKLzHZ3v6HxHZ6rOVJ2pBlMNphpMNZhqMNVgqsFyBMsRKIcTACcATgCcADgBcALgBMAJgBOAdRmxKnGr6xBOTKaaTDWZajLVZKrJVAmAEwAnAE4AnAA4AXAC4ATACUAQgCAAQQCCAAQBCAIQBCAIQBCAIABBAIIABAEIAhAEIAhAEIAgAMFmFWxWwWYVbFbBZhVsVsFmFWxWgWa1MYD-S9MRbnUTCoT0VjchPktvdWMTbtRUNyEkgVvdhD6xCifiVjchbtRb3fiLG5nqJ24VHWAT-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-XJx8vvp8urztH22O612p-VfXi9PLpbPd6aDX3_Yu_lZsldvL16_3fx42curdR8f-_r8dHVxttr--NsHt_uvVrxf__r-H28vXuz96j9_vXj3ejk9Orj-ibWHDzY_zrZ-2v6j3dX-b1YXuyf7jw62tnb2Hy-_fvLo6cHl6Yvt1cHBT3aufjhra-fh8uzN8nKd9OXiq72z6fTFtPji4tX1w350cPLw2Vd7m9xWez_dvf2NnffvTpdnz6fFj5-9_5DH3z98_eab66__Aw)

```scala
type Q=String;
def g(l:Q,n:Int,c:Q=""):Seq[Q]={if(n==0)Seq("");else{for{a<-l if a.toString!=c;b<-g(l,n-1,a.toString)}yield a+b}}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rZvPbhzHEYfveooJTyQiGUmcwIEQBVhudXeF3ak6GDkQhg8raqUwoJcKtUpiCHqSXHyJL3mjIA-THf7X76NsGQgEi9zW9FRN16f6XCLmn9-_OVmdrT7_91d7Tzbnf19dbPa-_u5fb7cvn_z2P1_89_z5X9Yn2-mPq9PN9O7RNL1Yv5y-2X3YX128evN0WlxcrL796svtxenm1dcHT6c_bU6307PLK6fpb6uz6WT1Zv1mt_Ll-q_7l4vTdPN1mvYWh8u9x7cfP7_79t7l1xcu7l2InfPCUq9YHn64cLjAgtzjUO9xqPdY6j2Weo-lZrrcZXr7-eD6u4ObS_b35jvuHv3yka-e8yrVg7trPjgw-7-d2KH91CNcLHWL6RbTLaaH_ONlWNhPrcuhJnaoiR1qYoea2CfUVhN7sNiyoFs0saUmttTETBMzTcw0MdPETBMzTcz0kE0P2XaH_AMk31GafXF8b-uvPk5p9g9DpOSQxx9-7imf5fou1y_k-oXEW8j1x3L9sVx_vPi0E1imlTbqp_1VXaZCkwpNFl1oujB0of4IVktLXdAoplFMo5hGKRqlaJSiD1c0StEoRaM0jdI0StMoTR-uaZSmUYZGGRplaJShUYY-3NAoVaNUjVI1StUoVaNUebhcpi6YLhRdaLqAm8qzpDKWylgqY6mMpTKWylgqY6mMpTKWylgqY6mMpTKWylgqY6mMpTKWylgqY6mMpTKWylgqY6mMpTKWylgqY6mMpTKWypgpY6aMmTJmypgpY6aMmXZL025p2i1Nu6VptzTtlqaMmTJmypgpY6aMmTJmypgpY6aMmTJmypgpY6aMmTJmypgpY6aMmTJmypgpY6aMmTJmypgpY0UZK8pYUcaKMlaUsaKMFWWsKGNFGSvKWFHGijJWtFsW7ZZFu2XRblm0WxbtlkUZK8pYUcaKMlaUsaKMFWWsKGNFGSvKWFHGijJWlLGijBVlrChjRRkrylhTxpoy1pSxpow1ZawpY00Za8pYU8aaMtaUsaaMNWWsKWNNGWvKWFPGmjLWtFs27ZZNu2XTbtm0Wzbtlk0Za8pYU8aaMtaUsaaMNWWsKWNNGWvKWFPGmjI2lLGhjA1lbChjQxkbythQxoYyNpSxoYwNZWwoY0MZG8rYUMaGMjaUsaGMDWVsKGNDGRvK2FDGhjI2tFsO7ZZDu-XQbjm0Ww7tlkMZG8rYUMaGMjaUsaGMVWWsKmNVGavKWFXGqjJWlbGqjFVlrCpjVRmrylhVxqoyVpWxqoxVZawqY1UZq8pYVcaqMlaVsaqMVWWsKmNVGavKWFXGqjJWtVtW7ZZVu2XVblm1W9Zdt7z9_EP_ABK137_5r---1X_9iBqS-W6lY8V0pQdWcJ-OXYZdysBuRaN3ZNiRYUeGvWqsXrFL_5pHR4YdGXZkaMjQkKEhQ0OGhgzxP-1hOHnDyZue_K7IgZWOFezSWLsV5TwYS89wt4JdeoYVVa6ockWVK6pcUeWKKldUuaLKFVWuqHJFlSuqXFHliipXVLmiyhVVrqhyR5U7qtxR5Y4qd1S5o8odVe6ockeVO7pNR7fp6DYd3aaj23R0m45u09FtOrpNR5U7qtxR5Y4qd1S5o8odVe6ockeVDVU2VNlQZUOVDVU2VNlQZUOVDVU2VNlQZUOVDVU2VNlQZUOVDVU2VNnQbQzdxtBtDN3G0G0M3cbQbQzdxuZu80lmP0q_f7fffNzsR7n79WGYecm5FFhybvTkEjcGNwY3BpLwI1zlRw9chYjOZ3Q-o_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-cX69XJn6d3l5-n_bPH0-bxtP7H6_XJdv3iYHr2--u987tk52-3r9_Or5e9Wm_WF6vtenn-zfPTzWp7er55c7n1JtLri9PN9myzf7Pj2d0tL694_2j-79HV62wP3-3pdPVW2-6uT6c_bLaPp5ObpV0Ge3sHT-efd9y8-nb7ztvpy2l_Mwf8xcHVG117VxHXZ7vHe3ed3u6pb7-fptX0uyfT2e3H3R1Wn23Pr0P97Nl0cvtHz-crP_rw05Ppl4_v7b05jPfTt6frsxe7OD-fnt97_PdXL_ldv-v33fXX_wE)

```scala
def generateCombinations(l: String, n: Int, c: String = ""): Seq[String] = {
    if (n == 0) Seq("")
    else {
      for {
        a <- l
        if a.toString != c
        b <- generateCombinations(l, n - 1, a.toString)
      } yield a + b
    }
  }
```

Comment: My solution was just golfed quite a bit (-10 bytes). Not sure if it translates to Scala, but wanted to let you know in case you could use that to golf yours.

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 67 bytes

```
def f($n):combinations($n)|join("")|select(test("(.)\\1";"x")|not);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYw7CsMwEAX7nEIsLlYgRJxPEx9F3kJWZJBJVhhtkUJ3V2JXgaR7MwNvWVu7x1nN2LG@hfycEntJmcsm6pITI4CuJT5iEJRYBAGtHsceBnh9CmfRQ7OuJ@WL6rhad6Tq9kNqzoEHMupEh30amP7g@QsNhE1dftWV3g)

Defines a function `f` which takes \$L\$ as input and \$n\$ as an argument.